# Sharepoint form writing to sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sharepoint

I want to build a form that will edit a table on SQL server. I known how to do it in ASP.NET (I need two drop down lists, gridview and button) but I want to make it as a part of SharePoint.
Can someone tell me what is the best technology to do that, I was looking at InfoPath but it seems I can not run it in web browser (only InfoPath filler). I just want to build simple form that is a part of Sharepoint and that is working in web browser. Please help.

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: You can create forms for Sharepoint with InfoPath **Designer**.

Comment: I have seen that but Is it possible to update SQl table directly from there?

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach to read/write from/to SQL databases in SharePoint is to sync the external data with SharePoint lists. In this way you have the full feature set of lists available with best performance and highest security. Users are just working with a synchronized copy of the external data in the lists. To sync the data you can program by yourself, use PowerShell or 3rd party sync tools like the Layer2 Cloud Connector.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice in SharePoint to directly change the database.
One way you can do is **Connecting to SQL Server Using the External Content Type Feature**

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/794/sharepoint-2010-connect-sql-server-external-content-type

If you want to change directly , As you already know how to do it in Asp.net , you can go for Visual Webpart with same asp.net gridview and connection string